# Mapquest - Distance Matrix presist Data

Tags: mapquest

I am in need for a Distance matrix(driving directions) for multiple locations ~1000 for a web application i am building.

The allToall attribute is what i am looking at in the Mapquest API http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/#matrix and then tried to read their TOS.
I would need to batch my request so that i don't over do the request part.

that being said after reading their Terms of service, i am not sure if i am allowed to store this data in my database. Not sure if i am reading this right, can someone tell me if it is OK to store the data locally and then use it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up posting it on the MapQuest community forums and as per the Terms of Service -  You cannot store any information from the MapQuest API.